# How do using namespace behave exactly?

Tags: c++, namespaces

For example we have this program:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a
{
    namespace b
    {
        namespace c
        {
            int alpha = 5;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace a;
    using namespace b;
    using namespace c;
    std::cout << alpha;
    return 0;
}
```

After successful compilation I thought that using namespace behaves like unix `cd`. On the first line of our code we were in the root `::`, then we moved to `::a`, `::a::b`, `::a::b::c`. But after such modification and successful run I was struck dumb:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace a;
    using namespace b;
    using namespace c;
    using namespace b;
    std::cout << alpha;
    return 0;
}
```

It still works, neither we are "in b directory"!

Even such constructions are allowed... :

```
namespace a
{
    namespace b
    {
        namespace c
        {
            int alpha = 5;
        }

    }
}

namespace b
{
    namespace a
    {
    }
}


void main()
{
    using namespace a;
}
```

Explain, please, using namespace behavior!

Comment: Namespaces is nothing like directories. If you want a shell-like metaphor  then aliases might be closer to the truth. When doing `using namespace a;` then the symbol `b` becomes an alias for `::a::b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `using namespace x;` just brings all of the names inside `x` into the current scope. The names inside `x` might include the names of other namespaces.

Take your first example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a
{
    namespace b
    {
        namespace c
        {
            int alpha = 5;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace a;
    using namespace b;
    using namespace c;
    std::cout << alpha;
    return 0;
}
```

Firstly, `using namespace a;` makes the name `b` available inside `main`. This allows us to then do `using namespace b;`, which additionally makes the name `c` available in `main`. Finally, we can do `using namespace c;` to make the name `alpha` available.

Now your second example:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace a;
    using namespace b;
    using namespace c;
    using namespace b;
    std::cout << alpha;
    return 0;
}
```

The first three lines are just as before, bringing the names `b`, `c`, and `alpha` into scope. Finally, repeating `using namespace b;` has no effect, since we've already brought all of the names from `b` into scope. Additionally, `alpha` has already been brought into scope so is still available on the next line. The final `using namespace b;` doesn't somehow undo this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a namespace effectively unwraps its contents.
It's why "using namespace std;" allows you to use "cout" without the std:: prefix. Rather than changing directories, think of it as moving the contents of the namespace into the current directory.